# android otg swap with touch keyboard

Tags: android, usb-otg

I'm new to android development. My first project needs a barcode scanning. I'm giving an option through OTG now. Now in my screen one more text box needs which takes input from keypress(for quantity). But in my android device keyboard is not getting enabled when i'm connected with OTG.

Am I missing any device level configuration? Or How can i control the input way programatically(OTG barcode Scanner/Touch Pad).

Thanks 
Binesh Nambiar C

Comment: I believe your question belongs to [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You may want to find a barcode scanner which does not function as a keyboard and so will not be handled by Android itself; then you can hook it up in your application using the Android USB host APIs.  You can also see if there's any chance those would let you claim a "keyboard" type of USB scanner away from the system, but that's uncertain.  Of course for limited amounts of scanning you can do it with the phone's camera, but that's inferior to a real scanner for frequent use.

Comment: @Kedarnath - this was explicitly asked as a development question, which probably means that the poster has options not available to someone who is merely trying to configure support for an existing app.

Comment: Thanks Kedarnath and Stratton. Both inputs are very valuable. The suggetion made by chris(Scan via camera) is already given,still there. But it lags in performance. 3-6 barcodes per minute. So only shifted it to OTG type. Can you explain some what detail about the other point. In market is barcode scanners availiable which does not work as a keyboard? It seems like you faced the same problem early. If so can you suggest some examples like that